# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap, wsdl

Ando bastante complicado haciendo un requerimiento a un webservice con PHP Soap. Los peticiones en las que consulto datos funcionan bien, pero hay una que realiza una reserva en un hotel y me arroja el error

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property

El siguiente código pide a ws que traiga los hoteles data una ciudad, funciona perfectamente. En la documentación se muestran los diferentes xml.

```
$xml = '<Request Version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<d>2</d>
<a>AF-AVV</a>
<l>esp</l>
</Request>';

$funcion = "GetHotels";
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
$wsdl = 'http://testxml.e-tsw.com/AffiliateService/AffiliateService.svc?Wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$xml_busqueda = simplexml_load_string($xml, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
 try {
     $respuesta     = $client->__soapCall($funcion, array('Parameters' => $xml_busqueda));
     echo "RESPUESTA DEL WEB SERVICE";
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($respuesta);
     echo "<pre>";
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

En el proceso que hace "Book" (reservar), es que me da el error SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property. El xml de la reserva es el que aparece en la documentación. Es bastante largo, pero contiene basicamente los datos necesarios para realizar una reservación.

```
$xml = '<Request Type="Reservation" Version="1.0">
<affiliateid>AF-AVV</affiliateid>
<language>esp</language>
<currency>PE</currency>
<uid>m2r32b14es10socxtxs4y4ht</uid>
<ip>201.147.113.232</ip>
<firstname>prueba</firstname>
<lastname>prueba</lastname>
<emailaddress>prueba@bestday.com</emailaddress>
<country>MX</country>
<address>bonampak 4</address>
<city>cancun</city>
<state>QROO</state>
<zip>77500</zip>
<total>12346.51</total>
<naturalperson>
<gender></gender>
<nationality></nationality>
<number></number>
<type></type>
</naturalperson>
<legalperson>
<businessname></businessname>
<number></number>
<type></type>
</legalperson>
<phones>
<phone>
<type>2</type>
<number>9981454221</number>
</phone>
</phones>
<hotels>
<hotel>
<hotelid>100</hotelid>
<roomtype>SUPOV</roomtype>
<mealplan>EP</mealplan>
<datearrival>20141113</datearrival>
<datedeparture>20141115</datedeparture>
<couponid></couponid>
<marketid>INTER</marketid>
<contractid>2</contractid>
<dutypercent>0</dutypercent>
<rooms>
<room>
<amount>985.34</amount>
<status>AV</status>
<ratekey>90cba867-f916-4fb9-8cb4-ec925ded0fb3</ratekey>
<adults>1</adults>
<kids>1</kids>
<k1a>5</k1a>
</room>
</rooms>
</hotel>
</hotels>
<flights>
<flight>
<quoteid>1885e28d-5198-4dd5-92e6-6cee14a66b1b</quoteid>
<ratekey>bc1b40db-b0fb-40ff-92b3-6b7cde0d8685</ratekey>
<passengers>
<passenger>
<isadult>Y</isadult>
<agechild></agechild>
<firstname>Prueba</firstname>
<lastname>Prueba</lastname>
<daybirthday>05</daybirthday>
<monthbirthday>06</monthbirthday>
<yearbirthday>1905</yearbirthday>
<numberfrecuent></numberfrecuent>
<idfrecuent></idfrecuent>
<naturalperson>
<type></type>
<number></number>
</naturalperson>
</passenger>
</passengers>
<contacts>
<contact>
<firstname>Prueba</firstname>
<lastname>Prueba</lastname>
<email></email>
<phones>
<phone>
<type>1</type>
<number>(+52)654654646</number>
</phone>
</phones>
</contact>
</contacts>
</flight>
</flights>
<shuttles>
<shuttle>
<shuttleid>599</shuttleid>
<shuttletype>R</shuttletype>
<adults>2</adults>
<kids>0</kids>
<airportarrival>Aeropuerto Internacional de Cancun </airportarrival>
<airlinearrival>AC</airlinearrival>
<datearrival>20140501</datearrival>
<hourarrival>18:00</hourarrival>
<flightarrival>123</flightarrival>
<airlinedeparture>PU</airlinedeparture>
<datedeparture>20140502</datedeparture>
<hourdeparture>04:00</hourdeparture>
<flightdeparture>456</flightdeparture>
<hotelid>640</hotelid>
<amount>724.8</amount>
</shuttle>
</shuttles>
<insurances>
<insurance>
<insuranceid>12</insuranceid>
<adults>2</adults>
<children>0</children>
<amount>105.1049</amount>
<ratekey>4f2b132f-6663-427a-aa75-61c5d8e37635</ratekey>
</insurance>
</insurances>
<cars>
<car>
<agency>2</agency>
<sipp>AR133</sipp>
<amount>869.76</amount>
<brancharrival>139</brancharrival>
<airportarrival>CUN</airportarrival>
<datearrival>20140501</datearrival>
<hourarrival>12:00</hourarrival>
<branchdeparture>139</branchdeparture>
<airportdeparture>CUN</airportdeparture>
<datedeparture>20140502</datedeparture>
<hourdeparture>12:00</hourdeparture>
</car>
</cars>
<tours>
<tour>
<tourid>413</tourid>
<serviceid>1</serviceid>
<cityid>NOCIUDAD</cityid>
<adults>2</adults>
<kids>0</kids>
<datetour>20140711</datetour>
<hotelname>Cancun Clipper Club, Cancun Zona Hotelera Punta Cancun, Mexico</hotelname>
<timetour>00:00</timetour>
<amount>2035.62</amount>
<dutypercent>0</dutypercent>
</tour>
</tours>
<payments>
<cardpayment>
<type>86</type>
<bank>BC3</bank>
<number>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</number>
<securitycode>1212</securitycode>
<expirationmonth>03</expirationmonth>
<expirationyear>2018</expirationyear>
<holdername>prueba prueba</holdername>
<address>bonampak 4</address>
<city>cancun</city>
<state>QROO</state>
<country>MX</country>
<zip>77500</zip>
<amount>12346.51</amount>
</cardpayment>
</payments>
</Request>';


$funcion = "Book";
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
$wsdl = 'http://testxml.e-tsw.com/AffiliateService/AffiliateService.svc?Wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$xml_reserva = simplexml_load_string($xml, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
try {
    $respuesta     = $client->__soapCall($funcion, array('Parameters' => $xml_reserva));
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();

    }
```

Como podrán notar, el código es el mismo. Sólo cambia el xml y la función "GetHotels" por "Book". A continuación el documento wsdl

http://testxml.e-tsw.com/AffiliateService/AffiliateService.svc?Wsdl

Agradezco su ayuda para salir de esta traba que me tiene varios días haciendo pruebas. Tal vez esté enfocando mal todo este asunto, pues no soy experto en Soap.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Activa la traza para saber que sucede con tu petición, activa las excepciones para detener el flujo en tu bloque try / catch y por último, maneja los datos de entrada en un array en lugar del XML completo para que sea más sencillo.

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
try{
 $client = new SoapClient('http://testxml.e-tsw.com/AffiliateService/AffiliateService.svc?Wsdl', ['trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS]);

 $parametros = [
  'affiliateid' => 'AF-AVV',
  'language'=>'esp',
  'currency'=>'PE',
  'uid'=>'m2r32b14es10socxtxs4y4ht',

  'hotels' => [
   'hotel' => [
    'hotelid' => 100,
    ...
   ],
   ...
  ],

  'total'=>'123456.51'
   ...
 ];

 $client->Book($parametros);

} catch (Exception $exc) {
 echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($exc, true));
}
```

A final de cuentas, el objeto de usar un WSDL para alimentar el cliente SOAP es que PHP pueda decidir dónde y como interpretar los datos de entrada conforme a ese documento. Si alguno falta o está mal posicionado el cliente SOAP te lo hará saber.

Comment: Gracias @solrac

Tal vez mi pregunta sea tonta pero estoy intentando probar lo que me indicas y me pregunto ¿cómo asigno valores a elementos del arreglo que están contenidos en otros elementos?

En mi caso específico 
    [affiliateid] => 'AF-AVV'
    [language] => 'esp'
    [total] => 12346.51
    [hotels] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [hotel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [hotelid] => 100

llevarlo a 
 $parametros = [
  'affiliateid' => 'AF-AVV',
  'language'=>'esp',
  'total'=>'123456.51',
   'hotelid' ?????
 ];

Comment: Solo tienes que incluirlo en la estructura del array. Cada nivel del XML es un array dentro del array. He actualizado mi respuesta para incluir el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Hice lo que me recomendó @solrac convirtiendo el xml en un arreglo y ahora es un "error desconocido" lo que me arroja

A continuación el código, con el arreglo :

```
    try{
     $client = new SoapClient('http://testxml.e-tsw.com/AffiliateService/AffiliateService.svc?Wsdl', ['trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, "compression" => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS]);

$parametros = Array
(
    'attributes' => Array
        (
            'Type' => 'Reservation',
            'Version' => '1.0'
        ),

    'affiliateid' => 'AF-TVOD',
    'language' => 'esp',
    'currency' => 'PE',
    'uid' => 'm2r32b14es10socxtxs4y4ht',
    'ip' => '201.147.113.232',
    'firstname' => 'prueba',
    'lastname' => 'prueba',
    'emailaddress' => 'prueba@bestday.com',
    'country' => 'MX',
    'address' => 'bonampak 4',
    'city' => 'cancun',
    'state' => 'QROO',
    'zip' => '77500',
    'total' => '12346.51',
    'naturalperson' => Array
        (
            'gender' => Array
                (
                ),

            'nationality' => Array
                (
                ),

            'number' => Array
                (
                ),

            'type' => Array
                (
                )

        ),

    'legalperson' => Array
        (
            'businessname' => Array
                (
                ),

            'number' => Array
                (
                ),

            'type' => Array
                (
                )

        ),

    'phones' => Array
        (
            'phone' => Array
                (
                    'type' => '2',
                    'number' => '9981454221'
                )

        ),

    'hotels' => Array
        (
            'hotel' => Array
                (
                    'hotelid' => '100',
                    'roomtype' => 'SUPOV',
                    'mealplan' => 'EP',
                    'datearrival' => '20141113',
                    'datedeparture' => '20141115',
                    'couponid' => Array
                        (
                        ),

                    'marketid' => 'INTER',
                    'contractid' => '2',
                    'dutypercent' => '0',
                    'rooms' => Array
                        (
                            'room' => Array
                                (
                                    'amount' => '985.34',
                                    'status' => 'AV',
                                    'ratekey' => '90cba867-f916-4fb9-8cb4-ec925ded0fb3',
                                    'adults' => '1',
                                    'kids' => '1',
                                    'k1a' => '5'
                                )

                        )

                )

        ),

    'flights' => Array
        (
            'flight' => Array
                (
                    'quoteid' => '1885e28d-5198-4dd5-92e6-6cee14a66b1b',
                    'ratekey' => 'bc1b40db-b0fb-40ff-92b3-6b7cde0d8685',
                    'passengers' => Array
                        (
                            'passenger' => Array
                                (
                                    'isadult' => 'Y',
                                    'agechild' => Array
                                        (
                                        ),

                                    'firstname' => 'Prueba',
                                    'lastname' => 'Prueba',
                                    'daybirthday' => '05',
                                    'monthbirthday' => '06',
                                    'yearbirthday' => '1905',
                                    'numberfrecuent' => Array
                                        (
                                        ),

                                    'idfrecuent' => Array
                                        (
                                        ),
                                    'naturalperson' => Array
                                        (
                                            'type' => Array
                                                (
                                                ),

                                            'number' => Array
                                                (
                                                ),

                                        )

                                )

                        ),

                    'contacts' => Array
                        (
                            'contact' => Array
                                (
                                    'firstname' => 'Prueba',
                                    'lastname' => 'Prueba',
                                    'email' => Array
                                        (
                                        ),

                                    'phones' => Array
                                        (
                                            'phone' => Array
                                                (
                                                    'type' => '1',
                                                    'number' => '(+52)654654646',
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        ),

    'shuttles' => Array
        (
            'shuttle' => Array
                (
                    'shuttleid' => '599',
                    'shuttletype' => 'R',
                    'adults' => '2',
                    'kids' => '0',
                    'airportarrival' => 'Aeropuerto Internacional de Cancun', 
                    'airlinearrival' => 'AC',
                    'datearrival' => '20140501',
                    'hourarrival' => '18:00',
                    'flightarrival' => '123',
                    'airlinedeparture' => 'PU',
                    'datedeparture' => '20140502',
                    'hourdeparture' => '04:00',
                    'flightdeparture' => '456',
                    'hotelid' => '640',
                    'amount' => '724.8',
                )

        ),

    'insurances' => Array
        (
            'insurance' => Array
                (
                    'insuranceid' => '12',
                    'adults' => '2',
                    'children' => '0',
                    'amount' => '105.1049',
                    'ratekey' => '4f2b132f-6663-427a-aa75-61c5d8e37635',
                )

        ),

    'cars' => Array
        (
            'car' => Array
                (
                    'agency' => '2',
                    'sipp' => 'AR133',
                    'amount' => '869.76',
                    'brancharrival' => '139',
                    'airportarrival' => 'CUN',
                    'datearrival' => '20140501',
                    'hourarrival' => '12:00',
                    'branchdeparture' => '139',
                    'airportdeparture' => 'CUN',
                    'datedeparture' => '20140502',
                    'hourdeparture' => '12:00',
                )

        ),

    'tours' => Array
        (
            'tour' => Array
                (
                    'tourid' => '413',
                    'serviceid' => '1',
                    'cityid' => 'NOCIUDAD',
                    'adults' => '2',
                    'kids' => '0',
                    'datetour' => '20140711',
                    'hotelname' => 'Cancun Clipper Club, Cancun Zona Hotelera Punta Cancun, Mexico',
                    'timetour' => '00:00',
                    'amount' => '2035.62',
                    'dutypercent' => '0',
                )

        ),

    'payments' => Array
        (
            'cardpayment' => Array
                (
                    'type' => '86',
                    'bank' => 'BC3',
                    'number' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'securitycode' => '1212',
                    'expirationmonth' => '03',
                    'expirationyear' => '2018',
                    'holdername' => 'prueba prueba',
                    'address' => 'bonampak 4',
                    'city' => 'cancun',
                    'state' => 'QROO',
                    'country' => 'MX',
                    'zip' => '77500',
                    'amount' => '12346.51',
                )

        )

);

    $salida = $client->Book($parametros);

    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo "<pre>";
    print_r($exc);
    echo "</pre>";
    // echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($exc, true));
    }
    echo "respuesta del ws";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($salida);
    echo "</pre>";
```

La excepción que muestra es la siguiente:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [BookResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [confirmationid] => 0
            [total] => 0
            [Error] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 600
                    [Description] => An unknown error has ocurred
                    [Data] => Affiliate Service
                )

        )

)
```